# How to make a sub list in md-list-item in Angular Material?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I have made a `md-list` on `side-nav` by using Angular Material. I want add a sub list belongs to `md-list-item`. Here is my code.

```
<md-sidenav id="sideNav" md-component-id="left"  class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z1 md-locked-open " layout="column" md-disable-backdrop >
    <md-content>

    <md-list>
       <md-list-item md-ink-ripple >
           <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i><div>Dashboard</div>
        </md-list-item >
       </md-list>
      </div>
      </div>
   </md-content>
</md-sidenav>
```

I want to add two sub-list when i click Dashboard button. Is it possible to do with Angular Material? Any help highly appreciate.

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://brilliantbritz.com/2015/06/17/creating-your-own-angular-material-right-navigation-menu/

Answer (score 0):

The very [Angular Material website](https://material.angularjs.org/) has a side navigation consisting of lists that are collapsed and expanded when you click on them.

They use `<ul>` and `<li>` markups, but that seems to be what you are looking for.